# Openlayer adding points in Openlayer draw feature

Tags: draw, polygon, openlayers, points

I am trying to use draw feature of openlayer (polygon). It is possible for the end user to draw a polygon. But I want to draw the polygon through java script. I am trying to use insertXY and insertDeltaXY functions of openlayer, but there comes a js error "**Object doesn't support property or method 'insertXY'**".

Follow is my chunk of code.

```
var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
        vectorLayer, 
        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon }
        );
map.addControl(draw);
draw.activate();

//Listen for sketch events on the layer
draw.layer.events.on({
   featureadded: that.PolygonAdded
});

//Draw polygon if provided from codebehind

//Insert a point in the current sketch given x & y coordinates    
handler.insertXY(cords[0], cords[1]); 
//Insert a point given offsets from the previously inserted point.
handler.insertDeltaXY(cords[2], cords[3]); 
handler.insertDeltaXY(cords[4], cords[5]); 
.....
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to determine if we could see more of your code. What is `handler`. `vectorLayer` and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `draw` object to insert points. According to the [OpenLayers documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html)
 the `OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature` exposes the methods `insertXY` and `insertDeltaXY`. I don't know if your `handler` object has these methods.

```
//Insert a point in the current sketch given x & y coordinates    
draw.insertXY(cords[0], cords[1]);
```